# Browser resize event in firefox addons

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to develop a viewport shower addons for firefox. I did the following code :

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var windows = require("windows").browserWindows;
var utils = require('window/utils');

exports.main = function() {

    var browserWindow = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    var window = browserWindow.content;

    var wid = new Widget({
        id: "xxxxxxxx-widget-1",
        label: "My Mozilla Widget",
        //content: window.screen.availWidth + "x" + window.screen.availHeight,
        content: window.outerWidth + "x" + window.outerHeight,
        width: 50
    });

    window.on("sizemodechange",function(){
        wid.content = window.outerWidth + "x" + window.outerHeight;
    });
};
```

It is working great for first view. But when I re-size the window then it is not working. How could I implement the browser `resize` event on this code?

Thanks in advance.